# What is the purpose of strlen($query)-2;

Tags: php, substr, strlen

I got this code from google and it fulfills my requirement, but I don't understand the meaning of this line:

```
substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2)
```

Could somebody explain it to me?

```
<?php
function insert($tablename, $parameter_order, $values)
{
    $query = "insert into $tablename (";
    foreach($parameter_order as $po)
    {
        $query .= $po.', ';
    }
    $query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2).') values (';
foreach($values as $v)
{
$query .= "'$v', ";
}
$query = substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2).');';
    return $this->makeQuery($query);
}
?>
```

Comment: Do you understand what `substr` and `strlen` each do by themselves? It should then be obvious what they do when you put them together.

Comment: You should really not use this and switch to prepared statements instead.

Comment: @jeroen You can't use placeholders for column names.

Comment: @Barmar True, you would need a white-list as well. For the table name as too. Like I said, don't use this :-)

Comment: Can you people help me with the code?

Comment: Check @Michael Jaros answer below. :)

Comment: 4 down votes . Thanks ,didn't expect it .. :'(

Comment: You should think about what you need. Do you really need a generic insert function like this? If so, you need to start over using the comments above to make it secure against sql injection. And you can post back here if you run into specific problems.

Comment: @ManiKandan: People will often downvote a question if they feel you haven't put much effort into a problem before asking here. You can prevent that by explaining in detail what you have tried or how you have understood the problem. Read more about [How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: Am honored with 4 down votes... Thanks. That's all i can say

Comment: @jeroen: I no need your suggestion, just ans to the question else better you .... Understand it..!!!

Comment: @ManiKandan Nope, not getting it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what those functions do exactly:

> `substr()` is used to generate a sub-string of specified length from another string.
>
> `strlen()` will return the length of the provided string.

Code `substr($query,0,strlen($query)-2)` removes **comma** and **space** from `foreach` Loop.

Answer (score 1):

The line removes the last comma and space from `$query`. These characters have been added in the `foreach` loop to glue together the elements of `$parameter_order`.

Note that this standard task is usually done better with the [`implode()`](http://php.net/manual/de/function.implode.php) function:

```
$query = "insert into $tablename (" . implode (', ', $parameter_order) . ' ) values (';
```

Comment: Your confusing me.. Where will this line fit exactly in my code

Comment: @ManiKandan: I wrote this line for you to learn, not to put it in your code. You usually use a statement like that instead of a `foreach` loop if you want to concatenate elements of an array. If you have no idea what I'm talking about, maybe you should start with some basic PHP tutorials.